# preg_match and UTF-8 in PHP make hashtag

Tags: php, utf-8, hashtag

I have this code:

```
$text= "#h #gg #مصر";
$get_hash = preg_match_all("/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z-أ-إ-آ-ا-ب-ت-ث-ج-ح-خ-د-ذ-ر-ز-س-ش-ص-ض-ط-ظ-ع-غ-ف-ق-ك-ل-م-ن-ه-و-لا-لا-لآ-لأ-لإ-ى-ي-ئ-ة-ء-ؤ_]+\w*)/", $text, $matches);
$array_hash = implode("",$matches[0]).""; 
$hash = str_replace('#', ', ', $array_hash);
echo "hash (".$hash.")<br />";
echo $text;
```

Result:

```
hash (, h , gg)
#h #gg #مصر
```

I want a result like that:

```
hash (, h , gg , مصر)
#h #gg #مصر
```

Comment: http://3v4l.org/DmXGf I don't see any problems. are you sure you saved your file as utf-8 too?

Comment: And your interpreter is using utf-8 too? or is it working in iso-8859-1 mode?

Comment: Try with `[^ \"\n\r\t<]*`

Answer (score 1):

To take whatever in **UTF-8** we use this `[^ \"\n\r\t<]*`

Answer (score 0):

i know its too late just for others to know

i modify this function to make it allow Arabic characters

as fallowing

```
 function get_hashtags($string, $str = 1) {
 preg_match_all('/#(\w*[a-zA-Z-أ-إ-آ-ا-ب-ت-ث-ج-ح-خ-د-ذ-ر-ز-س-ش-ص-ض-ط-ظ-ع-غ-ف-ق-ك-ل-م-ن-ه-و-لا-لا-لآ-لأ-لإ-ى-ي-ئ-ة-ء-ؤ_]+)/',$string,$matches);

  $i = 0;
  if ($str) {
   foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
   $count = count($matches[1]);
   $keywords .= "$match";
    $i++;
    if ($count > $i) $keywords .= ", ";
   }
  } else {
  foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
  $keyword[] = $match;
  }
  $keywords = $keyword;
 }
return $keywords;
}
```

**usage :**

```
    $string = "<p>#عاشت #فلسطين حرة عربية يوجد 2 هاشتاج لازم اشوفهم في الداتا بيز</p>";
$myArray = get_hashtags($string, $str = 0);
 $max = sizeof($myArray);
for($i = 0; $i < $max;$i++)
{
 echo "#".$myArray[$i]."<br />";
}
echo "$string"
```

**result**

```
#عاشت
#فلسطين
#عاشت #فلسطين حرة عربية يوجد 2 هاشتاج لازم اشوفهم في الداتا بيز
```